# Assign a range of IP addresses to an interface on OSX (Mac)

Tags: bash, macos, networking

I would like to assign a range of IP addresses in the 172.18.0.x network with mask 255.255.255.0 to my local loopback interface (lo).

How can I do this from the terminal in a Mac?

Background:
I can use ifconfig and the 'alias' command to add a single IP address to my local loopback interface. Example:

```
ifconfig lo0 alias 172.168.0.1
```

How do I do the same thing for all the IPs in the 172.168.0.x range?

Answer (score 1):

One at a time, with a loop.

```
for (( i=1; i<256; i++)); do
    ifconfig lo0 alias 172.168.0.$i
done
```